# Missing type specifer error

Tags: c++

I've got problem while including header files, in every header file i use

```
#pragma once
```

File structure:

```
Main.cpp  
- includes  
  Main.h  
  class definition

Main.h
- includes   
  "class.h"  
  "random_header.h"  
  others ( windows , fstream )  
  class declaration

Class.h
- includes
  "Main.h"
  class cApplication{ };

Other headers ( class, random_header ) include Main.h
```

errors in Main.h at class declaration:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'App' ( App is class name )
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I'll be thankfull for any help/tips.

Main.h code

```
#pragma once

#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx9.lib")

#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

#include "D3Ddefs.h"
#include "cApplication.h"

extern cApplication App; //error

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
```

Ok, theres more code as you asked, in my opinion posting whole thing is a bit pointless (if it isn't, tell me please), so I'll just add this what should be important.

Main.cpp

```
#include "Main.h"

cApplication App;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPreviousInstance,LPSTR lpcmdline,int nCmdShow)
{ ... }
```

D3Ddefs.h ( full )

```
#pragma once

#include "Main.h"

#define D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)

struct D3DVERTEX
{
float fX,
      fY,
      fZ;
DWORD dwColor;
};
```

cApplication.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Main.h"

class cApplication
{
private:
...
};
```

cApplication.cpp

```
#include "cApplication.h"


cApplication::cApplication(void)
{ ...
}
```

Comment: The header information is nice .. but it would be even nicer if you could post the snippet of code (a few lines before and after) that the compiler's complaining about.

Comment: where is `App` defined and is it in a namespace?

Comment: I generally get that error when I've left off a ; in one of my header class definitions or function declarations.  Go look at the last one in the header before your errors begin...

Comment: Added header file as you sked, App class is wrote in "class.h" and definied in main.cpp, none extra ';' found :(               @Daniel Its "class.h" and d3ddefs is "random_header.h", sry for that, switched names for better visualise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a circular inclusion issue. Manually replace each of those #includes with the file they include's content, in the order they happen, ignoring any file that was previously include, and you'll see that, in cApplication.cpp, "extern cApplication App;" happens above the declaration of cApplication.

As to how to solve this? Can't actually tell you without knowing *why* cApplication.h needs Main.h. If you can separate that dependency out, you should be alright. Are you trying to make cApplication some kind of [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), including Main.h so you can access that "App" variable?

Comment: Yes, you are right, Main.h in cApplication.h wasn't needed, I can include headers in other way. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. That's what we're all here for.

Answer (score 1):

First of all one should not rely on `#pragma once` as the pragma directives are compiler dependent and might cause you a lot of trouble when porting your code to some other platform/compiler.

What I prefer using is:

```
#ifndef __MY_HEADER_FILE_NAME__H
#define __MY_HEADER_FILE_NAME__H
...
... header file code here
...
#endif /* #ifndef __MY_HEADER_FILE_NAME__H */
```

Coming back to your code, the problem could be because of the above mentioned problem (very less likely though) or could be because of some error/typo in decelration of `cApplication App`.
There is also a possibility that `D3Ddefs.h or cApplication.h` is missing a semicolon some where in the file.

Figuring out the exact reason based on the info that you have provided is a bit difficult. If one of the above mentioned things don't work for you, try posting a smaller version of your code that is causing the problem

**[Update]**

It is compiling fine for me. I am using the updated code and modified this part:

```
class cApplication
{
private:
...  --> replaced this with "int a;"
};
```

SO I think the problem is some where in the `class cAplication` deceleration.

Comment: Alright, added some more code, I think #pragma isn't problem here, as it was happening to me long time ago, when I was writing in Dev-C++, and using header guards instead of pragma.

Answer (score 1):

From the error I think the headers are getting themselves into a mess. I can't see from the above exactly how it's going wrong, but if you include "cApplication.h" first, that then tries to include "main.h", which then tries to include "cApplication.h" again. In this case, the "#pragma once" or include guards will both prevent "cApplication.h" being included again (and therefore it won't parse the class definition at this point). It'll then continue to parse "main.h" and reach you trying to do "extern cApplication app" without ever touching the definition (which it would get to later once we're done with main.h).

You need to simplify the cross-dependency between the header files to stop this recursive inclusion of them. Split out the common library stuff into another header you can include in all the other headers and only try to include things that are absolutely necessary in headers. (i.e. why does D3Ddefs.h include main.h when it only needs windows.h and d3d9.h/d3d9x.h at the most for what it does).